# RGB pixel format in FreeType

Tags: c++, freetype

I'm having troubles understanding how the pixels are stored under FreeType, the core part of my problem is how to extract the RGB value after rendering the glyph.

```
typedef uint32_t Tindex;
//
FT_Render_Glyph(face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_LCD);
//
FT_Bitmap bitmap = face->glyph->bitmap;
FT_Glyph_Metrics metrics = face->glyph->metrics;
//
Tindex colStartPos = metrics.horiBearingX >> 6;
Tindex rowStartPos = metrics.horiBearingY >> 6;
//
for (Tindex y = 0; y < bitmap.rows; y = y + 3)
{
    Tindex row = rowStartPos + y;
    for (Tindex x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x = x + 3)
    {
        Tindex col = colStartPos + x;
        uint8_t r = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.width + x];
        uint8_t g = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.width + x + 1];
        uint8_t b = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.width + x + 2];
        img(col, row) = pixel{r, g, b, 255};
        // img and pixel are placeholders to simplify the code
    }
}
```

The official documentation doesn't specify how the pixels are stored, it simply says that the format is RGB, also my compiler says that the type for the values retrieved from `bitmap.buffer` is `float` but this can be the result of some type punning technique.

I did notice that when rendering in `FT_RENDER_MODE_LCD` the number of iterations is being triplicated so the math checks out, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and this snippet is just one of the many tries I have done.

Also, note that `bitmap.pitch / bitmap.rows` is equal to `1` in my case, I would expect it to be `3`.

Someone could explain how I'm supposed to read pixel values? It's possible to switch to an RGBA format?

From the docs, it looks like the format is *interleaved*, but it doesn't look like that

---

This piece of code is using boost, libpng and FreeType, it reproduces the problem that I'm experiencing and it's self-contained ( do not forget to customize the path to the TTF font )

```
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png_dynamic_io.hpp>
extern "C" {
#define FT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_RENDERING
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include <ftlcdfil.h>
}
#include <cstdint>
#define FONTFILE "/tmp/DroidSans.ttf"
#define IMGSIZE 400
typedef uint32_t Tindex;
int main()
{
    FT_Library library = 0;
    FT_Face face = 0;
    FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
    FT_Library_SetLcdFilter(library, FT_LCD_FILTER_LIGHT);
    FT_New_Face(library, FONTFILE, 0, &face);
    FT_Set_Char_Size(face, 0, 24 * 64, 300, 300);
    FT_ULong charcode = 0x003f;
    FT_UInt glyph_index = 0;
    glyph_index = FT_Get_Char_Index(face, charcode);
    FT_Load_Glyph(face, glyph_index, FT_LOAD_TARGET_NORMAL);
    FT_Render_Glyph(face->glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_LCD);
    FT_Bitmap bitmap = face->glyph->bitmap;
    FT_Glyph_Metrics metrics = face->glyph->metrics;
    Tindex colStartPos = metrics.horiBearingX / 64;
    Tindex rowStartPos = metrics.horiBearingY / 64;
    boost::gil::rgba8_image_t img{IMGSIZE, IMGSIZE};
    boost::gil::rgba8_image_t::view_t imgView{boost::gil::view(img)};
    for (Tindex y = 0; y < bitmap.rows; y++)
    {
        Tindex row = rowStartPos + y;
        for (Tindex x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++)
        {
            Tindex col = colStartPos + x;
            uint8_t r = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.pitch + x * 3];
            uint8_t g = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.pitch + x * 3 + 1];
            uint8_t b = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.pitch + x * 3 + 2];
            imgView(col, row) = boost::gil::rgba8_pixel_t{r, g, b, 255};
        }
    }
    boost::gil::png_write_view("img.png", imgView);
}
```

I compile this with

```
g++ -std=c++11 $(freetype-config --cflags) main.cpp -lpng $(freetype-config --libs)
```

Comment: What sort of output do you get with your code? (Last time I used FT, `glyph->bitmap` was still a simple grayscale bitmap.)

Comment: @Jongware I have no problem when using `FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL` but I need something better with subpixel accuracy, `FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL` gives me a gray palette that I have no problem with.

Comment: what you are doing should work (rgb in that mode seems to be a triplet of one-byte values), did you get any errors with that approach? The only change is that you should not up x by 3, it's the buffer pointer that moves by 3.

Comment: @Ashalynd I don't understand, It's interleaved or planar ? I have to shift values and do type punning stuff ?

Comment: It's a planar buffer, but you don't add the right offset when you iterating over your bitmap. Look at the docs: FT_Bitmap.pitch is the number of bytes per row. http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Bitmap

Answer (score 2):

AFAIU from the docs (http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Bitmap) your loop should be something like that:

```
for (Tindex y = 0; y < bitmap.rows; y++)
{
    Tindex row = rowStartPos + y;
    for (Tindex x = 0; x < bitmap.width; x++)
    {
        Tindex col = colStartPos + x;
        uint8_t r = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.pitch + x*3];
        uint8_t g = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.pitch + x*3 + 1];
        uint8_t b = bitmap.buffer[y * bitmap.pitch + x*3 + 2];
        img(col, row) = pixel{r, g, b, 255};
        // img and pixel are placeholders to simplify the code
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show how you use this code? difficult to answer without seeing that.

Comment: as I said, difficult to say without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: I have updated the first post, I'll delete previous comments since they are useless now.

Comment: `[y * bitmap.pitch + x*3 + OFFSET]` looks like a formula for interleaved access, not a planar one, but I still don't have any idea how pixels are stored in this buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Pixel_Mode) says that with the default `FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY` each pixel is stored in 1 byte representing a shade of gray. You can convert it manually to RGBA or perhaps you could use some Freetype features, like `FT_PIXEL_MODE_LCD` or `FT_Bitmap_Convert()`. I haven't tried this myself though.